# Remove-S3Bucket : The specified bucket does not exist

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I had created 3 buckets for testing and then later on deleted via PowerShell Command as below:

```
Get-S3Bucket| select -Skip 1 | foreach {Remove-S3Bucket -BucketName $_.Bucketname -DeleteBucketContent}
```

However, after couple of hours, I run Get-S3Bucket and I see the same buckets listed. I checked the console and found 3 buckets already there. I tried opening one of them and got "Data Not Found" error as per this screenshot:
Link:[https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=AE48A34880F3B8E4&id=AE48A34880F3B8E4%21142505&parId=AE48A34880F3B8E4%21111&o=OneUp]

I thought it might be a stale object, so tried creating another with the same name and it won't let me create one saying 'bucket already exists', as per below screenshot:
Link:[https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=AE48A34880F3B8E4&id=AE48A34880F3B8E4%21142504&parId=AE48A34880F3B8E4%21111&o=OneUp]

I tried again removing it from PowerShell, and get this error "The specified bucket does not exist", below screenshot:
Link:[https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=AE48A34880F3B8E4&id=AE48A34880F3B8E4%21142506&parId=AE48A34880F3B8E4%21111&o=OneUp]

Can someone suggest anything?

-kt

Comment: Not sure if it was a lag of so many hours but after 12+ hours these 3 buckets were gone

Comment: The issue got reproduced again, not sure if this is issue due to managing it from aws-powershell